# Wicket - Localizing date input field

Tags: html, date, web, input, wicket

I am working on an application whose target will be the greek market. My problem is that I want the date input fields to have the greek date format (which is dd-mm-yyyy) and the calendar to be in greek regardless of the browser settings. I suspect that there is some way to achieve this using the Locale attribute of either the Session, or the input field, in order to avoid using some 3rd party plugin (like the jQuery datepicker). Am I correct in thinking so? And if yes, what is the proper way to do this?

What I tried to do was setLocale("el") when initiating the input field and when creating a new session, both of which did not work out.

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date the displayed value depends on the browser's locale. Try with the *pattern* attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#handling_browser_support

Answer (score 0):

Override Application#newSession:

```
@Override
public Session newSession(Request request, Response response)
{
    final Session session = super.newSession(request, response);
    session.setLocale(yourFixedLocale);
    return session;
}
```

Comment: did that, didn't work. MySession extends the WicketBootSecuredWebApplication class, but I don't think the problem lies in there. Am I doing it wrong?


`final MySession session =  new MySession(request);
  session.setLocale(new Locale("el","GR"));
  return session; `

Comment: Are you sure that your **Session** extends an **Application** ? This would be wrong!